# Find a linear form which is not in the span$((l_n)_{(n\ge 0)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

> **Problem**
>
> Let $V$ be the vector space of all polynomial real coefficients and let $W$ be the subspace of $V^{\ast}$(The dual of $V$) spanned by the linear forms $(l_n)_{n\ge 0}$, where $l_n(P)=P^n(0)$.
> Prove that $W^{\perp}=${0},but $W^{\perp}\ne V$

The first part was quite easy and comes from definition of $W^{\perp}$.
But I'm stuck at the inequality part. The objective is to find a linear form which is not linear combination of $l_n's$ .

Here I'm seeing for any polynomial $P(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$ the coefficients can be written as $a_n=\frac{l_n(P)}{n!}$ .Then any new linear form created by using only coefficients will result the new linear form is linear combination of $l_n$ 's. Please  provide some hints to how to create a different linear form other than $l_n$'s.

Comment: You have not defined any inner product, so $W^{\perp}$ makes no sense. Also, $W^{\perp}=0$ implies that $W^{\perp}\neq V$ obviously.

Comment: @geetha290krm Here $W^{\perp}$ is the subspace of all those vector $v \in V$ such that $l(v)=0$ for all $l\in W$.

Comment: Look at the Taylor series of $p$. This is  not a finite linear combination of $l_n$'s.